# What is a good translation of "Rüstzeit"?

Tags: german-to-english, technical-terminology

I'm looking for a concise translation for "*Rüstzeit*". This is the time taken to reconfigure a machine for a new batch of work. (Installing new tools, new NC program, etc.)

"*Setting up time*" is one idea but sounds a bit too general.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: Funny thing: I know the word 'Rüstzeit' from pastors and the like, when they go to a training, they often call it Rüstzeit (weil sie ausgerüstet werden, they get equipped for their job)

Comment: @Hinek - yes, it has a similar meaning but I guess the boss isn't standing there doing a time and motion study ;-)

Comment: http://dict.leo.org/?search=r%C3%BCstzeit

Comment: I never heard that word in German before. Seems to be more a dialect, see also: http://bar.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rüsten_(Fertigungstechnik). BTW: @Gigili why is this question tagged with two tags, meaning the same?

Comment: Close! 1. als Frage nach einem engl. Ausdruck m.E. off topic. 2. eine simple "Google-das-für-mich"-Frage, bzw. leo.

Answer (score 9):

How about **Retooling time**? Retooling is the process of equipping a machine, factory, etc., with new, or different components.

Answer (score 7):

The [IATE](http://iate.europa.eu/iatediff/SearchByQuery.do) database (European Union terminology database) has entries for *Rüstzeit*:

- *dismantling time* for *Abrüstzeit* in labor law (“the time required for breaking down a machine (for process) after completing production”);
- *set up time* for *Aufrüstzeit* in labor law;
- *preparation time* and *time for clearing-up* in agriculture;
- *temps mort* (*idle time*) in technology (“that part of operable time during which a functional unit is not operated”).

The [Linguee](http://www.linguee.com/english-german/search?query=R%FCstzeit) translation database suggests *tooling time* or *retooling time* or *setup time* for *Rüstzeit* in this sense.